# Django Rest Framework and Stripe, best practice?

Tags: python, django, rest, django-rest-framework, stripe-payments

I'm struggling with philosophical questions in my DRF structure using the payement handler [Stripe](https://stripe.com). I'm selling a product that has a django model `Product` through my DRF REST API. I'm wondering if I should create the `Product` and then **handle the payment in my `create` view** as follow:

```
class ProductViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):

...

def create(self, request):
    serializer = ProductSerializer(data=request.data)
    serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
    product = serializer.save()

    try:
        response = stripe.Charge.create(
            amount=product.cost,
            currency="usd",
            source=request.data["token"], # Done with Stripe.js
            description="Product"
        )
        product.charge_id = response.charge_id

        ...
```

or instead, if I should **handle the payement in the serializer** of `Product`:

```
class ProductSerializer(serializers.Serializer):

    ...

    def create(self, validated_data):
        product = Product.objects.create(**validated_data)

        # Will raise an Excetpion and stop the creation:
        response = stripe.Charge.create(
            amount=product.cost,
            currency="usd",
            source=validated_data["token"], # Done with Stripe.js
            description="Product"
        )


        return product
```

Which one is the better practice? Or, do I completely miss the point and should do it differently?

Secondly, is there a way to embed Stripe.js and the required form in the Browsable API template for the `create` route so I can test my REST without the need of any frontend?

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion the right approach is a mix of the two provided approaches because you should send the `Stripe` request in the `ModelViewSet` class but save the `Product` entity only after the service's successful response.

Otherwise if the service's response is not successful I would rollback each database operation(with Django 1.6+ you can do it using `transaction.atomic()` documented [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/db/transactions/)).

I don't like your second approach because according to the DRF documentation about the `create` method of `serializers.Serializer`this method should only return a new Entity instance given the validated data, so I would not add other business logic.

Regarding the second question I would structure the `create` method to use an injected mock object for the `Stripe`request, in this way you can test your code regarding any frontend interaction (obviously in this way you don't do an integration test but a unit test).

Comment: Thanks. I'm simply charging after validating the data `serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)` but before creating the object `product= serializer.save()` in my view. It's a bit sad I have to retrieve some data from `request.data` to charge... Can you add more details (e.g. bit of code) on the second part?